# Visual Studio Add-in for displaying exceptions

Tags: visual-studio

has anybody heard of any add-in/extension to Visual Studio to display exceptions in a convenient way?

After years of using VS I hate the moment when an exception pops up and it tells you nothing - instead you browse to View Details and look at totally crappy form displaying inner exceptions where even reading the message is a pain.

Why after all these years (since VS2003) nobody has done anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

[VsErrorHandler](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f0448f3f-59ed-4ace-9171-97046366f032) replaces the exception modal dialog in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I was looking for. This displays exceptions thrown by Visual Studio itself - not by the software you are working on.